# Good way to cause SNMP traps on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, snmp

I want to do a little SNMP testing and want to issue some traps from a test Ubuntu box.  What are the easiest ways (for a Linux noob) to cause some traps to fire?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to have the snmp package installed.  "sudo apt-get install snmp" should install it for you if you don't have it installed already.  The package contains the command line tools for snmp from the Net-SNMP project.

After the package is installed use either snmptrap or snmpinfor depending on what you are trying to learn.  Look at the manpages and http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/ for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you can use snmptrap:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/snmptrap.1.html

Cheers